# Where I can find all variables for email template in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

In which class I can find all variables for email template in PrestaShop?

I mean something like {firstname} or {lastname}. Or maybe it depends by class method. For example. If I create new payment template then I need to go PaymentModule.php ?

Comment: No. I don't. I want to know, what variables I can use to create a email template. For example {firstname}.

Comment: You can create variables and pass to `Mail::Send` function. Is this what you need? :)

Comment: I was wrong? I speak English bad? Maybe I use another words. I want to modify some templates email. The question is. Where I can find variables for template ? That is all..

Comment: No wrong... It depends by the method that sends the e-mail. If you want to create a new payment template you have to see the `PaymentModule.php` and check the `ValidateOrder` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I say in the comment, it depends by the method that sends the e-mail. If you want to create a new payment template you have to see the `PaymentModule.php` and check the `ValidateOrder` method.
This is all the vars that you can use in your e-mail template:

```
$data = array(
'{firstname}' => $this->context->customer->firstname,
'{lastname}' => $this->context->customer->lastname,
'{email}' => $this->context->customer->email,
'{delivery_block_txt}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($delivery, "\n"),
'{invoice_block_txt}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($invoice, "\n"),
'{delivery_block_html}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($delivery, '<br />', array(
    'firstname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>',
    'lastname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>'
)),
'{invoice_block_html}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($invoice, '<br />', array(
        'firstname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>',
        'lastname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>'
)),
'{delivery_company}' => $delivery->company,
'{delivery_firstname}' => $delivery->firstname,
'{delivery_lastname}' => $delivery->lastname,
'{delivery_address1}' => $delivery->address1,
'{delivery_address2}' => $delivery->address2,
'{delivery_city}' => $delivery->city,
'{delivery_postal_code}' => $delivery->postcode,
'{delivery_country}' => $delivery->country,
'{delivery_state}' => $delivery->id_state ? $delivery_state->name : '',
'{delivery_phone}' => ($delivery->phone) ? $delivery->phone : $delivery->phone_mobile,
'{delivery_other}' => $delivery->other,
'{invoice_company}' => $invoice->company,
'{invoice_vat_number}' => $invoice->vat_number,
'{invoice_firstname}' => $invoice->firstname,
'{invoice_lastname}' => $invoice->lastname,
'{invoice_address2}' => $invoice->address2,
'{invoice_address1}' => $invoice->address1,
'{invoice_city}' => $invoice->city,
'{invoice_postal_code}' => $invoice->postcode,
'{invoice_country}' => $invoice->country,
'{invoice_state}' => $invoice->id_state ? $invoice_state->name : '',
'{invoice_phone}' => ($invoice->phone) ? $invoice->phone : $invoice->phone_mobile,
'{invoice_other}' => $invoice->other,
'{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
'{date}' => Tools::displayDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), null, 1),
'{carrier}' => ($virtual_product || !isset($carrier->name)) ? Tools::displayError('No carrier') : $carrier->name,
'{payment}' => Tools::substr($order->payment, 0, 32),
'{products}' => $product_list_html,
'{products_txt}' => $product_list_txt,
'{discounts}' => $cart_rules_list_html,
'{discounts_txt}' => $cart_rules_list_txt,
'{total_paid}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_paid, $this->context->currency, false),
'{total_products}' => Tools::displayPrice(Product::getTaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? $order->total_products : $order->total_products_wt, $this->context->currency, false),
'{total_discounts}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_discounts, $this->context->currency, false),
'{total_shipping}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_shipping, $this->context->currency, false),
'{total_wrapping}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_wrapping, $this->context->currency, false),
'{total_tax_paid}' => Tools::displayPrice(($order->total_products_wt - $order->total_products) + ($order->total_shipping_tax_incl - $order->total_shipping_tax_excl), $this->context->currency, false));
```

If you're creating a new module, you can pass all the vars that you needs, 'overriding' the `ValidateOrder` method

Answer (score 0):

The variables are the names of the columns in the database tables, for example: for the variable for the shipping without taxes value, you can consult the table `pr_orders` and the column you need, in this case is `total_shipping_tax_excl`, so you can use the value `{total_shipping_tax_excl}` to have this value in a mail.